# How to Remove duplicate entries while insertion in c++ array

Tags: c++

I am creating a c++ array program in which I am trying to get input from the user but during insertion I want to prompt the user for duplicate values. I have used a while loop and for loop inside, but it doesn't work if the user enters a duplicate value. He will be asked to enter the value again at the particular index.

```
int size=0;
int k;
int index=0;
int temp=0;
int aray1[2];
char ch='y';
while(ch='y') {
    for(k=0; k<=2; k++)
    {
        if(aray1[k]==temp) {
            cout<<"please do not enter duplicates";
            ch='y';
            index--;
        } else {
            aray1[index]=temp;
            index++
            ch='n';
        }


    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Will the array be of length 2 only

Comment: Gah, this indention violates my eyes. And there's at least one closing curly brace (`}`) missing. Or do you really use `system("pause")` in every `while` iteration?

Comment: Wow, an equal sign is missing in `while(ch='y')`, you are reading the 3rd element of `aray1`, you're comparing uninitialized values (`aray1[k]==temp`)...

Comment: You should use a std container in C++. There are very few places in C++ where you should use naked arrays. In this case the container you are looking for is a [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: @RedX: OP wants to prompt the user for duplicate values.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs The [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) member function returns the information whether the entered element was already in the set or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) instead.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

int main(){
  using namespace std;
  vector<int> v;

  int size=2;    

  while(v.size()<size){
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    vector<int>::iterator it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), i);

    if(it==v.end()) // i is not in v so insert it to the end of the vector.
      v.push_back(i);
    else
      cout << "Duplicate entered." << endl;
  }
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: Or just use a `std::set` which will only store unique values...

Comment: Yes, he could best use std::unordered_set, report "duplicate" based on the return value of insert operation and then collect the elements into a vector but I just wanted to give him a basic solution that is easiest to program.

Comment: The point is he doesn't need a `vector` nor an `unordered_set` a regular set will fit his needs perfectly.

Comment: Please don't use cplusplus as a reference. [It is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad).

Comment: @RedX: We are generally on the same page. OP wants to have an array of values I guess for random access. You push for "efficiency" a bit too early and the most efficient would be unordered_set for your worries anyway. Nevertheless, feel free to post your version! ;)

Comment: The usage of `set` in this case is not for efficiency but because it is idiomatic. It conveys the idea of "this container will not contain duplicates". Not because it is more "efficient" (in what?) then `vector`. Vector has other semantics (continuous-storage) then set.